# Text editor - float above other windows

Tags: text-editor

I'm looking for a text editor with the ability to float above other windows. As far as I know, Sublime and the native TextEdit don't have this feature. Is there some other program that does have this feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stickies!

The OS X version of this app that's been on Macs since System 7.5 has the ability to float, and become semitransparent.

[image: Stickies]

Technically it's a rich-text notetaking app rather than a plaintext editor, but it might satisfy your use case.

Another option (quite the polar opposite of Stickies) would be to use an editor within Terminal, and use [TotalTerminal](http://totalterminal.binaryage.com) to display it in "visor" mode.

Finally, it looks like there was an open-source project that added these kinds of window management features to any app of your choosing called [Afloat](https://github.com/millenomi/afloat/). The original project hasn't been updated in 3 years, but one of the forks might be functional on the current iteration of OS X.

Answer (score 2):

Bean
http://www.bean-osx.com/Bean.html

Use option-command-F to float document window (or in menu Documents / Window / Float Window).

Answer (score 1):

The Notes app has this feature.

Open a note in it's own window (double-click the title) and then the option is under Window/Float on Top.

You can assign a keyboard shortcut to it in system keyboard settings (I use <kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>)

Answer (score 0):

Scribblet is the best so far - it's actually just a modified version of TextEdit so that it allows you to take notes and it stores them in folders like Finder does.
http://www.palemaverick.com/scribblet/

Comment: it just doesn't add tables :(